# does $Q_AV_{AB}=Q_BV_{BA}$ in this case

Tags: energy, potential-energy

Sorry fo unclear title but I can't find any suitable on for this question. Here is what my text book says about how to find out the energy of a system of charge of n particle.

[image]

What I don't know is if it ok to take that $R_{31}=R_{13}$. I means to make calculation first we must take an reference frame so it's obviously that $R_{31}=-R_{13}$

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Why do you introduce a sign in a scalar [distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance) $\geq 0$?

Comment: I think that to calculate the potential energy means doing line integral from some reference (usually assume that potential is zero at infinity). Since it take the reference point there must me positive and negative direction. Also there's thing called orientation in line integral.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confusing vector and scalar $R$. The potential between two charges depends on the magnitude of $R=|\vec{R}|$, not on the vector. So in this case $R_{13}=R_{31}=|\vec{R}_{13}|$.